# Children of HBox are restricted to top left of HBox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create a grid/tile like page using HBoxes and display text inside of the HBoxes, but the children(Label and Button) are restricted to the top leftof the HBox. I've been using scenebuilder, but even when I set the Layout X and Y the children stay in the same positions. All of the HBoxes have this problem.

**FXML Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.improved.HelloController">
   <children>
      <HBox fx:id="hBox" prefHeight="100.0">
         <children>
            <TabPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="${hBox.width}" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Home">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <HBox fx:id="lastRaceHBox" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <VBox>
                                       <children>
                                          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick" text="Hello!" />
                                          <Label fx:id="welcomeText" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="68.0" />
                                       </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                 </children></HBox>
                              <HBox fx:id="nextRaceHBox" layoutX="400.0" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                              <HBox fx:id="upcomingDatesHBox" layoutX="800.0" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                              <HBox fx:id="rankingsHBox" layoutY="386.0" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                              <HBox fx:id="goalsHBox" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="386.0" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                              <HBox fx:id="playerInfoHBox" layoutX="800.0" layoutY="386.0" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Dates">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Race">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Player Info">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab text="Player Search">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                  </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.example.improved;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

**Main Application Class**

```
package com.example.improved;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1280, 960);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that the `alignment` property offers a variety of `Pos` values.

Comment: @trashgod changing that worked, thanks. Is there any way to freely move the children?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "freely move the children".  HBox is an opinionated layout pane.  You can configure constraints or layout hints on the nodes in the pane to control their layout, but it is not for arbitrarily placing items.  If you want to arbitrarily place items, then don't use a HBox, use a layout type that allows that (e.g. a Group, Pane or AnchorPane).  But then you lose the auto-layout functionality for sizing and placement that is provided by layout management panes like HBox.

Comment: @jewelsea Okay that makes sense. I guess I will change the layout type. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to freely move the children?

The [`HBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) API outlines the available constraints. In particular, "The alignment of the content is controlled by the `alignment` property, which defaults to `Pos.TOP_LEFT`." You can specify the desired [`Pos`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Pos.html) value. You may also want to experiment with the settings that control *Resizable Range* and *Optional Layout Constraints*.

As a concrete example, [`LayoutSample.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/layoutsamplejava.htm#JFXLY220), illustrated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY131), specifies a grow constraint that allows `helpIcon` to stay on the right as the stage is resized:

```
HBox.setHgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

More examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20setHgrow).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at Optional Layout Constraints.